# unable to resize root partition present on extreme left

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I am trying to resize the root partition with an Ubuntu 20.04 live USB stick. I am able to resize the /home partition to create some free space but unable to move it to the left side. Move/resize buttons are disabled `/home` partition and on freed-memory block.

It's a dual boot system, /sda4 and /sda8 belongs to windows 10. is there something I can do to add more space to root?

Here is the partition layout for reference:

[image]

Comment: Warning: Anything you do could break one or both OSes. Make a backup if you have not already done that. In the table there are some key-icons - did you mount the partitions? If they are not mounted you should be able to move them...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @Virsacer wrote the partitions have to be unmounted. 
Before you start take notes of the UUID's of the partitions. 
Make your /home partition smaller. And move it to the right ( not to the left: you then won't be able to create more space for / ).
Delete your swap partition ( in between / and /home ). Now you will have space after your / partition.
Enlarge your / partition ( leave enough space for your swap partition ).
Make your swap partition. ( I always make my swap partition at the end of my disks. )
See if the UUID's have changed. If not your done. 
If they have changed you need to modify your Grub config file and Fstab.
Do all this from a live environment and make backups first.

Comment: I gave up on separate boot and swap partitions (they eventually caused problems when upgrading) and go for a monolithic partition (or lvm) with swap file now. No noticeable bad effects and it's easier IMO.

Comment: OP has a seperate swap partition, hence this answer. Indeed when only using one Linux based OS a swap file is a good option.